How to install Old-release package library on Ubuntu 24.04.1 desktop amd64 (Apple silicon MacBook air4)
I’m trying to install a program that is only supported on Linux in a Ubuntu 24.04.1 desktop AMD64 environment within UTM.
Currently, Ubuntu is running properly within UTM. I’m in the process of installing the libraries necessary for the program, but I'm encountering issues.
After running:
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update

I’m stuck with the following command:
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 g++-5 g++-5-multilib libgfortran3:amd64 libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60
Each time, I get the error: E: Unable to locate package <library_name>.

I’ve tried solutions suggested on international forums that I found through Google, but they haven’t worked. One suggestion was to modify the repositories in vim (I’m using vim because command+c doesn’t work in nano):
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources

I added the focal-security address, but it didn’t help. (The Ubuntu code name I’m using is "noble.")
Here’s a reference link I used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73464111/libncurses-so-5-library-missing-in-ubuntu-22-04-installation-for-arm64-rapsberr
I also tried downloading and installing the libraries manually:
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ncurses/libtinfo5_6.4-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -I libtinfo5_6.4-2_amd64.deb
rm -f libtinfo5_6.4-2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ncurses/libncurses5_6.4-2_amd64.deb

I ran these commands to replace one of the problematic libraries (libncurses5:i386):
sudo apt install libn32ncurses5-dev

(Result: failed)
sudo apt install libncurses5
sudo apt install libncurses5-dev -y

(Results: both succeeded)
This method was also found on an international forum, but even though some libraries installed successfully, others still resulted in errors.
I tried searching for alternative libraries that could replace the problematic ones:
libncurses5:i386
g++-5
g++-5-multilib
libgfortran3:amd64
libicu-le-hb0
libiculx60

I searched using "noble" for all the above libraries, but I couldn’t find anything.
Additionally, according to the simulation program’s manual, I tried replacing i386 with i686, but this didn’t work either.
I’m not sure why some libraries won’t install. Out of around 20 library files, only these 6 are problematic.
Additionally I found the following article on an old 2015 blog in Korea (https://huammmm1.tistory.com/506).
*The version of Ubuntu we are using has a supported period for each release (for the regular version, it is 9 months, for LTS versions, it is 5 years, etc.). Once the support period for a specific version ends, the update repository and package repository for that version are no longer supported. Whether or not the support for your version of Ubuntu has ended can be checked using the following link:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29
In my case, I was using Ubuntu 11.04 Natty, and support for Natty ended in October 2012.
Since the support for my Ubuntu version has ended, I can no longer use the update and package repositories. Therefore, when I ran sudo apt-get update, I got an error like the one shown above, saying that it couldn’t find the IP address for the domain. And since the repository couldn’t be updated, running sudo apt-get install would also give the error "unable to locate package."
Solution:
If you want to continue using the repositories on an unsupported Ubuntu version, you need to change the repository server listed in the /etc/apt/sources.list file to the old-releases server.
First, open the /etc/apt/sources.list file using vi to see what information it contains.
The key part to look for is:
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com
In my case, this means the repository server is set to us.archive.ubuntu.com. To continue using the repository, change this to old-releases.ubuntu.com.
You can use the substitution command in vi like this:
:%s/us.archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g
While you’re at it, change the other two repositories as well:
:%s/security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g
:%s/extras.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g
After making these changes, run sudo apt-get update, and then you can install packages using sudo apt-get install.
Reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release*

Thank you for taking the time to read my message. If you have any suggestions or even partial advice, I would greatly appreciate it.

Ubuntu does not guarantee backwards compatibility. Older package may be incompatible with newer releases of Ubuntu. This is due to the way Debian-based systems are designed. Consider running your application in a container or other virtual environment using an older release of Ubuntu that is compatible with your software.

Now I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.1 desktop amd64.
Then using Ubuntu 22.04 amd64 can be a solution?
Because simulation program manual is based on Ubuntu 22.04 64-bit.

Yes, that's another solution. Ubuntu 22.04 will continue to receive community support and security patches until April 2027. Pro subscribers will get security patches until 2032.

Thank you so much. Your comment helped me a lot. I'll back with review.
